# SWTOR: Refer a Friend

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the Star Wars the Old Republic MMO, can two new subscribers "refer" each other so they both get the referral rewards?

Answer (score 2):

From the game's [official site](http://www.swtor.com/info/friends):

*As an active Subscriber, you have a personal referral link to send to your friends!*

- *Refer friends who have never had a SWTOR account.*
- *Invite previous Subscribers who have been unsubscribed for 90 days or more.*
- *Tell your friends to use the link as the first step in creating a new account or logging back in to an existing account. By clicking through the link to create an account or log in, they will be registered as your "Referral."*

So, if both of you have active accounts, you can give a referral link to each other. Then you can both create a new account or both use another, expired account that is older than 90 days, and reap those benefits for your active accounts. Easy!

There may even be a possibility (if the developers have looked over this exploit) to save two of your referral links, wait for 90 days for your active accounts to expire, and give them a boost with your referral links. Efficient!